# Modified Zeckendorf represention

Tags: math, numbers, addition, bitstring

Given `x` as searched integer and `k` as minimum zeros between 2 ones.

Example:

`x` := 7,`k` := 0
Binary represention: 111

`x` := 7,`k` := 1
Binary represention: 1010

`x` := 7,`k` := ?(>1)
Binary represention: ?

How can i calculate the binary represention for `k` > 1? I know that for `k` := 0 I use the binary represention, for `k` := 1 i use the zeckendorf represention (a `1` represented by a fibonacci number)

But how can i create the bit string for `k` > 1?

Thx in advance.

Comment: what's x=3 with k=1 and x=3 with k=2 in binary? just curious, tho

Comment: @player0 if I understand correctly, x=3 and k=1 should be 100 and x=3 with k=2 is what he's looking for